# creating squares through points stored in an array, p5.js

Tags: javascript, for-loop, processing, p5.js

So, after the user has created a square, i want to create small squares within that big square, 
for every line, i am running a loop where loop starts at point 0 and goes till point 1 , The problem i am facing right now is that, when the loop has created square from x of point 0 to x of point 1, i want to +1 in y of point 0 and run the same loop, i am confused on how to do that. maybe nested for loop.
Thank you.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

var pts = [];
var bts = [];
function mousePressed()
{
    if (pts.length == 4) {
        pts = [];
    }
    pts.push([mouseX, mouseY])
    if (bts.length == 4) {
        bts = [];
    }
    bts.push([mouseX, mouseY])
}

function draw() {  
      background(220);


      // draw the lines between the points
      for (var i=0; i < pts.length-1; ++i) {

          line(pts[i][0], pts[i][1], pts[i+1][0], pts[i+1][1]);
      }

      var close = pts.length == 4;
      if (pts.length == 4) {
          // draw line from 1st point to at point
          line(pts[pts.length-1][0], pts[pts.length-1][1], pts[0][0], pts[0][1]); 
      }

      else if (pts.length > 0) {
          // draw a rubber line from last point to the mouse
          line(pts[pts.length-1][0], pts[pts.length-1][1], mouseX,mouseY); 
      }

  if (pts.length==4)

  {  text("value of point 0 : "+pts[0][0],255,200);
    text("value of point 1 : "+pts[1][0],255,255);

      for (var j =1 ; j<=(pts[1][0]-pts[0][0]);j++)
           { 
      square((pts[0][0]+j), pts[0][1],1);


    }
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a rectangle, it is sufficient to draw a diagonal line. The 4 points of the rectangle, can be calculated by the 2 points of the diagonale:

```js
// rectangle points
let rpts = [pts[0], [pts[1][0], pts[0][1]], pts[1], [pts[0][0], pts[1][1]]]
// draw rectangle
for (var i=0; i < rpts.length; ++i) {
    line(rpts[i][0], rpts[i][1], rpts[(i+1) % rpts.length][0], rpts[(i+1) % rpts.length][1]);
}
```

The inner rectangles have to be draw in 2 nested loops. But you've to calculate the minimum and maximum coordinates. Note possibly the first point is somewhere at the bottom right and the 2nd point is at the top left:

```js
let x0 = min(pts[0][0], pts[1][0]);
let x1 = max(pts[0][0], pts[1][0]);
let y0 = min(pts[0][1], pts[1][1]);
let y1 = max(pts[0][1], pts[1][1])  
for (var x = x0; x < x1; x += 5) {
    for (var y = y0; y < y1; y +=5) {
        square(x, y, 4);
    }
}
```

[`noLoop`](https://www.processing.org/reference/noLoop_.html) stops Processing from continuously executing the code within `draw()` and [`loop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loop) restart the continuously executing.
Call `noLoop` when the inner triangles are draw and call `loop()` when a mouse button is pressed.

See the example:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}

var pts = [];
var bts = [];
function mousePressed()
{
    if (pts.length == 2) {
        pts = [];
    }
    pts.push([mouseX, mouseY])
    loop()
}

function draw() {  
    background(220);

    if (pts.length == 2) {
        // rectangle points
        let rpts = [pts[0], [pts[1][0], pts[0][1]], pts[1], [pts[0][0], pts[1][1]]]
        // draw rectangle
        for (var i=0; i < rpts.length; ++i) {
            line(rpts[i][0], rpts[i][1], rpts[(i+1) % rpts.length][0], rpts[(i+1) % rpts.length][1]);
        }
    }
    else if (pts.length > 0) {
        // draw a rubber line from last point to the mouse
        line(pts[pts.length-1][0], pts[pts.length-1][1], mouseX,mouseY); 
    }
      
    let c = color(255, 204, 0);
    fill(c);
    if (pts.length==2) { 
        let x0 = min(pts[0][0], pts[1][0]);
        let x1 = max(pts[0][0], pts[1][0]);
        let y0 = min(pts[0][1], pts[1][1]);
        let y1 = max(pts[0][1], pts[1][1])  
        for (var x = x0; x < x1; x += 5) {
            for (var y = y0; y < y1; y +=5) {
                square(x, y, 4);
            }
        }
        noLoop()
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, i am finding cpu being utilized when the inner squares have been created, that's why i was trying to use noLoop(), is there any way to stop this utilization.

Comment: @SilentHG Oh, I see. In this case `noLoop()` is the right choice. But you've to add [`loop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loop) to `mousePressed`. I've chnged that in the answer.

Comment: I have 1 more step before the completion of my project, 
my last step is to change the color of the small squares when mouse hovers over them (is that possible through mousemove function) or should i just create the big square first and when mouse hovers inside it, it creates square on that place, I am trying to make a mouse detection (sort of thing).

Comment: @SilentHG *"when mouse hovers over them"* - in this case you've to repaint the scene continuously. This means you've to remove `noLoop` and `loop`. You've to test `if (mouseX >= x && mosueX < x+5 && mouseY >= y && mosueY < y+5)` in the inner loop and to set the `fill` color dependent on the result. Or do the color have to change permanently? Anyway, this seems to be a new question.

Comment: Yes the color has to change permanently, if the current color is yellow by default, the new color should only change specific square's color when mouse is over them, This is a new question, i'll do my research (maybe i'll find some function which will help me in this query), and if i get stuck somewhere, i'll post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i used a nested loop, and created another variable (y) which had value of y of point 0 and in parent loop i was increment-ing inside the variable (y) and in child loop i was running the loop for square, Thank you.

```
        function setup() {
      createCanvas(400, 400);
    }

    var pts = [];
    var bts = [];
    function mousePressed()
    {
        if (pts.length == 4) {
            pts = [];
        }
        pts.push([mouseX, mouseY])
      }

    function draw() {  
          background(220);


          // draw the lines between the points
          for (var i=0; i < pts.length-1; ++i) {

              line(pts[i][0], pts[i][1], pts[i+1][0], pts[i+1][1]);
          }

          var close = pts.length == 4;
          if (pts.length == 4) {
              // draw line from 1st point to at point
              line(pts[pts.length-1][0], pts[pts.length-1][1], pts[0][0], pts[0][1]); 
          }

          else if (pts.length > 0) {
              // draw a rubber line from last point to the mouse
              line(pts[pts.length-1][0], pts[pts.length-1][1], mouseX,mouseY); 
          }
      let c = color(255, 204, 0);
      fill(c);
      if (pts.length==4)

      {  
        for (var k = 0; k<=pts[3][1]-pts[0][1];k+=5)
             {
               if (k==pts[3][1]-pts[0][1])
               {
                 noLoop()
               }
             var y = pts[0][1]+k;
          for (var j =1 ; j<=(pts[1][0]-pts[0][0]);j+=5)
               { 

          square((pts[0][0]+j), y,4);
               }

        }
       }


    }
```

I think there are more efficient methods, please answer, if you know.